# TS generics in functional react components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I have a functional component that takes a generic U. How can I access the keys of U and the values of U to use in another generic? CellBase and Matrix come from the 'react-spreadsheet' library. Here's the code:

```js
interface DataEditorAndViewerPageProps<T> {
  getAll: () => Promise<T[]>
  add: (input: Partial<T>[]) => Promise<T[] | ZodMiddlewareError[]>
  updateById: (id: string, input: Partial<T>) => Promise<T | ZodMiddlewareError>
  deleteById: (id: string) => Promise<number | NonZodError>
  selectedColumns: string[]
}

export default function DataEditorAndViewerPage<U extends {
  [key: string | symbol]: unknown
}>(props: DataEditorAndViewerPageProps<U>) {

...

const [spreadsheetHeaders, setSpreadsheetHeaders] = useState<CellBase<keyof typeof U>[]>([]);
  const [addedRows, setAddedRows] = useState<Matrix<CellBase<typeof U[keyof typeof U]>>>([[]]);

...

}
```

For both lines I get: 'U' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

Comment: Remove the `typeof` before `U`?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid any and unknown for production.

If you need a callback you can most likely just use `() => void` or `() => Promise<void>`

If you don’t know the types needed, you should look into a types file or refer to documentation of whatever library you’re using.

As per using functional programming for React components, this is a pretty solid template:

```
export const MyComponent = (props: Props): JSX.Element => <></>
```

Your components shouldn’t need to be so ‘smart’ that you end up writing many lines of possibly unnecessary code.

Comment: So instead of using a generic U I should use a union type of everything U could be? I thought this was an appropriate use of unknown...when you don't know what the values could be until you pass in the type argument, so it extends an object with unknown properties.

Comment: Your types should be explicit enough to be useful, not so fluid that you’re doubling your coding going away from JS to TS. I would avoid generics in my React components if possible. You can use a “variant” prop that is a union type of strings that can be used to conditionally render appropriate components.

Comment: Well this component doesn't conditionally render components based on the type, it uses a particular shape of data that will change depending where the component is used. So I want to pass the shape in as the type argument when I use the component and then the component knows that the cells should either be the keys of the shape or the values of the shape. Even if this isn't the best architectural approach, how can I use the keys of a shape and the values of a shape? For future reference. Thanks a bunch for your help and advice.

Comment: You would need the exact type. What’s the library you’re using? Is it built in house? If so, may want to create the type using TS Utility Types such as Partial or Record. In the case you need a highly custom type with better auto fill you may need a MappedType (Probably not the case).